# Distribute DIVS evenly or equally... yes I know I should use a table

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code / structure:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="div1">text</div>
 <div id="div2">more text</div>
 <div id="div3">nice text</div>
 <div id="div4">bad text</div>
 <div id="div5">hello world</div>
 <div id="div6">foo</div>
 <div id="div7">bar</div>
 <div id="div8">Dick Beatie</div>
 <div id="div9">Chuck Norris</div>
 <div id="div10">Brian Blessard</div>
</div>
```

and say I have the following CSS:

```
#container{
  overflow:auto; 
  width:100%;
}

#container div{
 float:left;
 padding:10px;
 text-align:center;
 width:10%;
}
```

The DIVs within the container are an equal size but don't fit within the container! How do I make them fit as they spill onto the next line currently. Please don"t say I should use a table, I know I should use one. I also realise that I could reduce the width of the DIVs however I"d then have to adjust the width of the container.

Thanks for the advice.

Ps. I bet some joker says use a table!

Comment: How would ten divs at 10% ever fit into 100% with the 10px padding? If you add padding, they cannot be at 10%.. they will always overflow.

Comment: It depends on what the real width is since you are setting width with percent and padding with actual pixels.  You could do 8% width with 1% padding (I think padding is added to both sides?? I don't remember for sure).  The 9% you are suggesting would work but only at certain widths where, 10px * 2 (each side) * 10 divs = 200 pixels, therefore where the width is 2000 pixels because you would have 10% (200 pixels) left over for padding.

Comment: Good description! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`box-sizing: bordex-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing) to make padding included in width.

Comment: I agree with this with the caveat that it is unsupported on older browsers. The less elegant, but more robust solution would be to add divs inside of your existing divs1-10 and apply the padding to the innermost divs.